# MustUseReturnValueAttribute does not show warning/exception if method contains out parameter

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, attributes, resharper, jetbrains-rider

Just as the title says, this attribute is ignored if the method contains any parameters with "out", is this a bug? Does anyone know another attribute in C# that can throw an error/warning in that case?

(added unity tag because this happens in unity, didn't test it on a standalone project)

In case you're wondering why I need an attribute like this, it's for cases where the return value is an IDisposable object that needs to be disposed once the parameter with "out" is no longer used.
E.g.:

```
    [JetBrains.Annotations.MustUseReturnValue]
    public PooledObject<List<Character>> GetCharactersOnSide(bool isLeftSide, out List<Character> characters)
    {
        PooledObject<List<Character>> pool = ListPool<Character>.Get(out characters);
        foreach (Character character in _characters)
            if (character.IsLeftSide == isLeftSide)
                characters.Add(character);

        return pool;
    }
```

Edit 1: Thanks to @Ruzihm I know now that this issue has already been reported on https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-486462.

I am however still looking for a workaround, will update the post when I find one.

Comment: I dont know much about jetbrains but it seems like this is in their bug tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-486462

Comment: If you find a workaround, please don't edit the question. Instead please write it below as a [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) so people can upvote the question and different solutions separately!

Comment: Why actually going this way? Doesn't your `PooledObject<List<Character>>` anyway have a reference to the `List<Character>`? => Couldn't you just access it via the returned `PooledObject<List<Character>>`? => what purpose does the `out` parameter have that is not already covered anyway?

Comment: @derHugo No, the PooledObject does not have a reference to the list, returning just it isn't enough.

Comment: I think the workaround would then be: Store the list reference in the returned `PooledObject` (may I ask what the generic parameter and the list passed to the constructor is good for if you don't store the reference?)  And forget about `out`

Comment: The PooledObject is a struct internal to unity so I can't edit it, the generic parameter is used to define which is the element type of the list I'm pooling. Having both the struct and the list is important because the struct contains information about how to dispose the list. I did implement a custom struct that stores both, but It required so much boilerplate code that it was simply not worth it, for now I'll just wait for jetbrains to fix the bug and hope I never forget to dispose the list.